# What happens to the covariance matrix when the errors are independent?

Tags: regression, variance, covariance, matrix

I was wondering, what happens to the covariance matrix of the errors, when I assume that all the errors are stochastically independent?

Is the covariance matrix still:
$$\sigma^2I = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2 & ... & 0\\. & . &.\\ 0 & ... & \sigma^2\end{bmatrix}$$

I really appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean 'still'? The covariance matrix is

$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_u=
\begin{bmatrix}
E(u_1^2)&E(u_1u_2) & \cdots & E(u_1u_n)\\
E(u_1u_2)&E(u_2^2) & \cdots & E(u_2u_n)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
E(u_1u_n)&E(u_2u_n) & \cdots & E(u_n^2)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so under the assumptions that 
$$
E(u_i)=0 \, \forall \, i\\
E(u_iu_j)=0\, \forall \, i\neq j\\
E(u_i^2)=\sigma^2 \, \forall \, i
$$
we can see that 
$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_u=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2&0 & \cdots & 0\\
0&\sigma^2& \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0&0 & \cdots & \sigma^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
=\sigma^2 \boldsymbol{I}_n
$$
as you say.

Comment: His question might go a bit deeper assuming he means that maybe the assumptions do longer hold. In any case he'll have to specify.

Comment: Note the requirement of the assumption that the error terms all have the same variance; that is, $E(u_i) = 0 \forall i$ and $E(u_i^2) = \sigma^2 \forall i$. This is necessary for saying the covariance matrix has the same $\sigma^2$ value on all the diagonals.

Comment: Instead of "still" one might even say, "even more so", as uncorrelatedness of the errors is already enough to get $\sigma^2I$, but if independence moreover holds, uncorrelatedness is implied.